# Convert .php file to .html for pdf view

Tags: php, html, pdf

I want to create temporary lets say "temp.html" file after getting data from the form so as to print it in PDF file format.

For example, in my script file "test.php", I want to convert it to test.html with data in it so as to print it in PDF file format.
Please guide me.

Comment: You can use PHP WkHTMLtoPDF library: https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf

Comment: or you can use TCPDF, FPDF, mPDF etc PHP PDF generator to generate PDF with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript for creating a temporary HTML page and call the print function immediately after that.

For example, you have an array **form_data** which contains all the data from your form. So the support function can be written as follows:

```
function PrintFunc(form_data)
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'fullscreen="yes"');
    mywindow.document.write('<html>');
    mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css' media='print'>");
    mywindow.document.write("@media  print {");
    mywindow.document.write("@page  {size: A4 landscape; max-height:100%; max-width:100%}");
    mywindow.document.write("}");
    mywindow.document.write("</style>");
    mywindow.document.write('<body onload="window.print(); window.close();" >');
    mywindow.document.write('<div align="center">');
    for(var i = 0; i < form_data.length; i++){
       mywindow.document.write(form_data[i]+"<br/>");
    }
    mywindow.document.write('</div>');
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/
    return true;
}
```

Now you just call above function from onClick of a button or from anywhere you want. Hope it can help you.